# I can't access SDK Tools tab in settings

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm on the latest Android Studio 2.1, I installed it on existing SDK, when I go to `Settings/Appearance & Behaviour/System Settings/Android SDK` I can see that it detects my installed SDK although with a warning of whitespace path, but SDK Tools and SDK Update Sites tabs are greyed out I think, I can't access them.
Any help on that?

Comment: I'm having the same problem (on Android Studio 2.3). Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FilipeRamos I think I moved the SDK to a folder without spaces, in the D: drive.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me too! =)

Comment: @FilipeRamos glad to hear it

Comment: Thanks a lot bro@JonneyShih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Window's `Enable Show Hidden Files` in 
the Control Panel/Appearance and Personalisation/File Explore options?

Double click on it, and go to view and check mark it and hit apply.

You will find a hidden folder another `sdk` in File Explorer `C:\Users\"your administrator name"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

Copy all the files from here to `C:\android\sdk`, restart Android Studio, and enjoy.